# Metacello dependency on a package from github project

Tags: github, pharo, metacello

How can one depend directly on a package from a github repo? (Assuming the project has no baseline, or there is a reason not use the baseline.)

I've tried the following spec

```
spec
    package: 'Magritte-XMLBinding'
    with: [ spec
        repository: 'github://magritte-metamodel/XML-Bindings:master/repository' ].
```

However it failed (*Could not resolve: Magritte-XMLBinding [Magritte-XMLBinding.package]*),  and in Monticello browser under the repo I see only `Magritte-Tests-XMLBinding`.

What is more, when I look at the unpacked repo (in `github-cache/`), only the `Magritte-Tests-XMLBinding` has been unzipped.

The unpacked `Tests` package is the first in alphabetical order, which makes me feel like Metacello spec just grabs the first package without thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using git (and github), you cannot depend on packages but in complete projects. You can, however, depend on a project but load just one package of that project. 
normally this definition should work:

```
spec
    baseline: 'XMLBindings'
    with: [ 
       spec
          repository: 'github://magritte-metamodel/XML-Bindings:master/repository';
          loads: #('Magritte-XMLBinding') ].
```

However, while this answer is correct in general, in this case **it will not work** because the author of the project didn't included any `baseline` definition that would allow this kind of dependency definition to work, which suggests me he just uses that project as a mirror of the real one... so here you have three possible solutions:

1. send a pull request to author with a baseline
2. contact the project author and ask to add a baseline
3. use the original source instead the github mirror

Comment: From the behavior it looks more like incomplete implementation, because it downloaded the correct repo, unpacked it, and only then it broke apart (essentially on a local filetree repo)